# What is the meaning of "I am on my word"?

Tags: meaning

Does "I am on my word" mean that one keeps their promises? Or does it mean that one still believes in what one has previously said?

Comment: It depends on the context. Typically when "on" precedes *my word*, it's a promise.

Comment: @Soudabeh: It's a site for English lovers. We don't like people callously writing `u` and `r` for `you` and `are`. Please try to avoid it. And its `liar`, but that probably was an honest mistake.

Comment: What you are looking for is "I am true to my word".

Comment: Might be: "*I am, on my word*" with a missing comma.

Comment: May be helpful, Urban Dictionary says _man of my word_  means someone who **believes they tell the truth**, **keeps promises**, and **doesn't make outrageous claims**. E.g. "If I say that I'm going to do something, I will do it, you can count on me... I'm a man of my word".

Comment: I am (implicit whatever the trait which is being considered) *comma* upon my word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, "on my word" will introduce a statement, or be appended to a statement as a kind of emphatic afterthought, or it will be injected as a parenthetic, as an indication that what is being said is true. The speaker is affirming the truth of the statement.

> On my word, it was at least nine stories tall, and it was spitting fire.
>
> It was at least nine stories tall, and spitting fire — on my word!
>
> It was at least nine stories tall  —on my word—   and spitting fire!

And following up on the conjecture by Wayfaring Stranger:

**Are you really a NASA astronaut?

-- I am, on my word.**

A variant of "on my word" is "you have my word" or "you have my word on it".

Comment: Using indentation creates preformatted code blocks which don't word-wrap (because word-wrapping something marked as code might break it; some programming languages are sensitive to whitespace). The problem this causes for readers is that quotes so formatted require horizontal scrolling. To avoid that, it's better to use the Markdown for blockquotes (unless you really are quoting code, of course!), which is to prefix such lines with a `>`. If you want paragraph breaks between such blockquotes, separate them with a sole `>` on a line by itself.

Comment: I'd like to know if there is " to be on someone's word" in English" or not.

Comment: @Soudabeh No, there is not. Native speakers would not phrase anything as you have done in your original question.

Comment: It is a promise; an oath or guarantee. (from 10th c.)

`I give you my word that I will be there on time.`

Comment: We can say "He told me so, on his word" or "I have it, on his word".  But "to be" on his word, no.

Comment: Dear Dan and Tim! Thanks a lot! You made me sure that There is not such an expression in English! And ithat's a great help! :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Free Dictionary, *on my word* or *upon my word* can mean "indeed; really." Basically, if you put this phrase before or after a claim, you are emphasizing that what you are saying is really true:

- **On my word**, I will do what I can to help you.
- **Upon my word**, I will do what I can to help you.
- I will do what I can to help you, **on my word**.
- I will do what I can to help you, **upon my word**.

The Free Dictionary also points out that when *Upon my word* is used by itself, it is "used as an exclamation of surprise or astonishment." This is often shortened to *My word*:

- **Upon my word!** Do you have to make so much noise?
- **My word!** Do you have to make so much noise?